# Unexpected token p in JSON at position 0 in fetch

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, async-await, try-catch

I created a signup form, In this I m posting data from react client to the node server where I created a signup route to handle that signup form.

**Here we are posting data to the server.**

```
async function submitHandler(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            try{
                const response = await fetch("/signup", {
                    method: "POST",
                    body: JSON.stringify({
                        name: name,
                        email: email,
                        password: password
                    }),
                    headers: {
                        "Content-Type": "application/json"
                    }
                })
                console.log(response);
                const data = await response.json();
                if(data.error){                          //This code of line to make sure that if there is any error then it should be catchable by the catch block.
                    throw new Error(data.error);
                }
            }
            catch(e){
                console.log(e.message);            //Here I m getting error -> unexpected token p in JSON at position 0.
            }
        }
```

**This is the route where I m posting data.**

```
router.post("/signup", async(req, res) => {
    const {name, email, password} = req.body;
    try{
        const XYZ = await User.ValidatingUser(name, email, password);       //Here we are calling a function to check email exist or not before create an account.
        const user = new User({
            name: name,
            email: email,
            password: email
        })
        await user.save();
        return res.send("Posted successfully");
    }
    catch(e){
        return res.json({error: e.message});                            
    }
    
})
```

**This is the function which I m calling in the signup route to check email is exists or not.**

```
//This code is to check that email exists or not. If the email exists then you can't signup.

    userSchema.statics.ValidatingUser = async(name, email, password) => {
        if(!name || !email || !password){
            throw new Error ("Please add all the fields");                     
        }
        const user = await User.findOne({email: email});
        if(user){
            throw new Error("That email is already exist");
        }
    }
```

When I click on the signup submit button, first it shows error -> **unexpected token P in JSON at position 0.**
But When I again clicked on the signup submit the form then it will show this error -> **That email already exists (which is returned by our server).**
So it means data is saving in our DB.
**See this Image.**
**[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FB5Mk.png)**

Answer (score 0):

You didn't well format the JSON.

You have use this JSON stringify method when you send data to server :

```js
JSON.stringify({
    name: name,
    email: email,
    password: password
})
```

**Update:**

The real issue come from `return res.send("Posted successfully");`, but it's well malformatted JSON.

So, the way to fix it is the same: `return res.send({error: "Posted successfully"});`

Comment: But I wrote this line of code when I m posting data to server by using shorthand property. You can see that in first page where I am posting data to server using fetch. I wrote this in first page while I am posting data to server.                                          body: JSON.stringify({
           name,
           email,
           password
 }),

Comment: No, the body is only like `JSON.stringify({name});` but JSON work as `key: value`, so you have to precise what the key's name

Comment: So it means you are saying that here shorthand property will not work.

Comment: I just tried this approach also but that didn't work too. It is still showing the same error.

Comment: Ok so I suggest you to log the entire error object, maybe it will contains further data. Also, I suggest you to : Create JSON object outside of your body creation. Write it in console, and use it in body. Then, you check the validity of printed json thanks to json validator

Comment: I made the changes in question. Please go through this and please try to solve this. And go through the image maybe it can help you to solve this problem.

Comment: Yes but the error message doesn't tell where the error is, so please replace `console.log(e.message)` by `console.log(e)`