# Error "Unexpected token P in JSON at position 0 in fetch"

Tags: json, try-catch, fetch-api

I created a signup form, In this I'm posting data from react client to the node server where I created a signup route to handle that signup form.

**Here we are posting data to the server.**

```
async function submitHandler(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            try{
                const response = await fetch("/signup", {
                    method: "POST",
                    body: JSON.stringify({
                        name: name,
                        email: email,
                        password: password
                    }),
                    headers: {
                        "Content-Type": "application/json"
                    }
                })
                console.log(response);
                const data = await response.json();
                if(data.error){                          //This code of line to make sure that if there is any error then it should be catchable by the catch block.
                    throw new Error(data.error);
                }
            }
            catch(e){
                console.log(e.message);            //Here I'm getting error -> unexpected token p in JSON at position 0.
            }
        }
```

**This is the route where I'm posting data.**

```
router.post("/signup", async(req, res) => {
    const {name, email, password} = req.body;
    try{
        const XYZ = await User.ValidatingUser(name, email, password);       //Here we are calling a function to check email exist or not before create an account.
        const user = new User({
            name: name,
            email: email,
            password: email
        })
        await user.save();
        return res.send("Posted successfully");
    }
    catch(e){
        return res.json({error: e.message});                            
    }
    
})
```

**This is the function which I'm calling in the signup route to check email is exists or not.**

```
//This code is to check that email exists or not. If the email exists then you can't signup.

    userSchema.statics.ValidatingUser = async(name, email, password) => {
        if(!name || !email || !password){
            throw new Error ("Please add all the fields");                     
        }
        const user = await User.findOne({email: email});
        if(user){
            throw new Error("That email is already exist");
        }
    }
```

When I click on the signup submit button, first it shows error -> **unexpected token P in JSON at position 0.**
But When I again clicked on the signup submit the form then it will show this error -> **That email already exists (which is returned by our server).**
So it means data is saving in our DB.
**See this Image.**
**[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FB5Mk.png)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find it.

It was difficult but it's `res.send("Posted successfully");` the issue.

You are to send a string as JSON, which is NOT JSON.

So, basically you have to do like:

```js
res.send({message: "Posted successfully"});
```

Just: try to don't [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68343129/unexpected-token-p-in-json-at-position-0-in-fetch/).

Comment: Thank you so much. You finally solved it.... And sorry for posting it another time.

Comment: No problem, I understand ! :)